# $X$ is a r.v. given $f(x)=2x\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$ a density function calculate $Y=X^2$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, density-function, change-of-variable

**QUESTION:** Let $X$ be a random variable with density function given by $f(x)=2x\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (where $\chi_{[0,1]}$ is the indicator function). Calculate the density function of $Y=X^2$.

**MY ATTEMPTY:** First of all, let's check that $f$ is a density function.

1. Clearly we have $f(x)\geq 0$ once the indicator function is give by $\chi_{[0,1]}(x)= 1$ if $x\in [0,1]$, and $\chi_{[0,1]}(x)= 0$ otherwise. Then $f(x)=2x$ if $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(x)= 0$ otherwise. Thus, indeed $f(x)\geq 0$, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
2. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1} 2x dx= 1$

From 1 and 2 it follows that f is a density function.

Now, we are going to calculate $Y=X^2$.
We have that $f_Y(y)=F'_Y(y)$ if $F'_Y$ exists. Hence,

\begin{align*}
F_Y(y)&=P(Y\leq y)\\
 &=P(X^2\leq y)\\
 &=P(X\leq \sqrt{y})
\end{align*}
$\implies F_Y(y)=F_X(\sqrt{y})$ this means that the diferenciability of Y works where X works.

Now, defining, $h(y)=\sqrt{y}$ we have that $h'(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}, \; \forall y\in \mathbb{R}.$

By the chain rule follows

\begin{align*}
F'_Y(y)&=F'_X(y)\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}, \; \forall y \in \mathbb{R}\\
 &=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} f_X(\sqrt{y})
\end{align*}

where
$$
    f_X(h(y))=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
    1 &\;\mbox{if}\; y \in [0,1]\\
    0&\;\mbox{otherwise}
 \end{array}
   \right. 
$$
$$\iff 0\leq \sqrt{y}\leq 1 \iff 0\leq y \leq 1$$

Therefore, $Y$ is a continuous function and its density is given by
$$
    f_Y(y) = f_X(h(y)). |h'(y)|=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
    \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} &\;\mbox{if}\; y \in [0,1]\\
    0&\;\mbox{otherwise}
 \end{array}
    \right.
$$

**MY DOUBT:** Is my answer right? Would you please check it for me? My question is precisely because I don't understand where I have to use $f(x)=2x$ when I'm calculating $Y=X^2$.

Comment: Check the line where you have written $f_X ( h(Y)) = 1 if y \in [0,1]$ and ........

Comment: So, there is where I'm using $f(x)=2x$ ? Is this? Sorry, I didn't understand what you asked me to check. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incorrect. Since $f_X(x) = 2x \cdot \chi_{[0,1]}(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h(y) = \sqrt{y}$, it follows that $$ \begin{aligned} f_Y(y) = f_X( \sqrt{y} )  \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y}} = 1 \ \forall y \in [0,1] \ \end{aligned}$$

and $f_Y(y) = 0$ otherwise, therefore $f_Y = \chi_{[0,1]}$.